# Java allows to assign byte to java.lang.Short but not to java.lang.Integer

Tags: java, type-conversion, wrapper, autoboxing

```java
final byte b = 12;  
Short s = b;  
Integer i = b;
```

Program compiles fine for Short but for Integer compilation fails with "incompatible types" message.

I am having difficult time trying to understand this behavior. I could not find anything for this specific scenario..

Comment: use **int** instead of **Integer**

Comment: It's not a 100% duplicate because it doesn't specify why `Short` is allowed, but `Integer` isn't so I retracted the closevote. Nevertheless very related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014171/widening-and-boxing-java-primitives

Comment: In my opinion, the "very related" question doesn't have an adequate answer - it just has a bunch of people making wild speculations.  I think it would be a mistake to close this.

Comment: Not only that, but the very related question's correct answer is wrong. Clearly byte is autoboxing to Short even though Short is larger than a byte. So why wouldn't byte to Integer work? Is it because it's greater than "2 levels of carelessness" higher? Seems arbitrary.

Comment: The plot thickens: Removing the 'final' keyword causes the Short autoboxing to generate a compiler error as well. That might be some clue as to the cause of this strange behavior.

Comment: And another weird nuance: `Character c = b` compiles just fine too.  But `char`s are unsigned! So what happens when you change `b` to `-12`? It then fails to compile!

Comment: There is a good answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/25294449/3593530

Answer (score 7):

I attempted to duplicate this with a wider group of assignment contexts:

```
final byte b = 12;
Byte b2 = b;
Character c = b;  // Only an error if b isn't final
char c2 = b;      // Only an error if b isn't final
Short s = b;      // Only an error if b isn't final
short s2 = b;
Integer i = b;  // Error, as indicated in the question
int i2 = b;
Long l = b;     // Also an error
long l2 = b;
Float f = b;    // Also an error
float f2 = b;
Double d = b;   // Also an error
double d2 = b;
```

Assigning not just to a `Integer`, but also to a `Float`, a `Long` or a `Double` is also an error.

Interestingly, if the original declaration of `b` was NOT `final`, then assigning to a `Character`, a `char`, or a `Short` fails also.

[Section 5.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) sheds a little light on the subject of assignment contexts and their allowed conversions.

> Assignment contexts allow the use of one of the following:
>
> - an identity conversion (§5.1.1)
> - a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2)
> - a widening reference conversion (§5.1.5)
> - a boxing conversion (§5.1.7) optionally followed by a widening reference conversion
> - an unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) optionally followed by a widening primitive conversion.

This covers all of the conversions to wider primitive variables, which are always allowed, whether `b` is `final` or not.  (That holds unless `b` is negative, in which case the assignment to an unsigned `char` (or `Character`) would fail.)  Continuing:

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type byte, short, char, or int:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.
> - A narrowing primitive conversion followed by a boxing conversion may be used if the type of the variable is:
>
>   - Byte and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type byte.
>   - Short and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type short.
>   - Character and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type char.

Because `b` is `final`, the expression `b` is a *constant expression*, allowing it to be narrowed from the `int` constant expression `12` to `byte`, `char`, or `short` and then boxed to `Byte`, `Character`, or `Short`, but strangely, not to `Integer` or anything "above".  The only possible explanation I can think of is that constant expressions that are subject to a primitive narrowing conversion aren't specifically allowed to be converted to `Integer`, `Long`, `Float`, or `Double`.

If `b` isn't `final`, then the narrowing followed by boxing isn't allowed, and a non-constant expression can't be promoted from `byte` to `char` either.

Comment: `Character c = b;  // Only an error if b isn't final` (or b is negative.)  Great answer!

Comment: @MarkPeters True.  As stated in the JLS quote above, "and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable".  A negative `final` `b` would cause `char c = b;` to fail with an error also.

Comment: *but strangely, not to `Integer` or anything "above"* I think that is to be expected since at that point you're working with `Short` and `Integer` and there is no widening possible on these wrapper types. See [$JLS 5.1.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.5): **A widening reference conversion exists from any reference type `S` to any reference type `T`, provided `S` is a subtype of `T`.** and obviously there is no connection between `Short` and `Integer` directly.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Yes, but I found it strange that a widening primitive conversion followed by a boxing conversion isn't specifically allowed.