# Java type error when compiling code with javac 8 which worked fine with javac 6

Tags: java, typeerror

I have this class, which is a simplification of some code I found in a project that is being ported from Java 6 to Java 8:

```
public class Unification {

    final class Box<A> {}

    final class MyMap<A, B extends Box<? extends A>> {}

    MyMap<?, ?> getMap() {
        return new MyMap<Object, Box<Object>>();
    }

    <A, B extends Box<? extends A>> void setMap(final MyMap<A, B> m) {}

    void compileError() {
        setMap(getMap());
    }

}
```

It's a very small example to merely showcase the problem, the actual code makes a bit more sense. The issue seems to be quite general though, hence the abstract example. The core issue is the following: for some reason, javac does not want to accept an expression with type `MyMap<?, ?>` as the argument to the `setMap()` method, even though this should, according to my understanding, be well-typed.

The code compiles without errors with javac 6, but I get this obscure error message when I use javac 8:

```
C:\System9\KWS_sparse\sourcesNG\Domain\src\uz\Unification.java (21:9) error: method setMap in class Unification cannot be applied to given types;
required: Unification.MyMap<A,B>
found: Unification.MyMap<CAP#1,CAP#2>
reason: inference variable A has incompatible bounds
equality constraints: CAP#1
lower bounds: Object
where A,B are type-variables:
A extends Object declared in method <A,B>setMap(Unification.MyMap<A,B>)
B extends Unification.Box<? extends A> declared in method <A,B>setMap(Unification.MyMap<A,B>)
where CAP#1,CAP#2 are fresh type-variables:
CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
CAP#2 extends Unification.Box<? extends CAP#1> from capture of ?
```

The error message seems to indicate that no unification can be found for the first type parameter of `MyMap`, javac cannot find a type that unifies with both `CAP#1`, which represents the first wildcard argument in the actual parameter to `setMap()`, and `A`, which is the corresponding type parameter of the formal parameter of `setMap()`. Even though it seems to me that `A` and `CAP#1` should be perfectly unifiable, they would then both represent the existential type introduced by erasing the actual types in the signature of `getMap()`.

Can anyone spot what is going wrong here? Was javac 6 erroneously accepting this code? Also, is there a not-too-intrusive (and javac 6 compatible) way to guide javac 8 towards the right unification?

EDIT: I tried the suggestion to introduce a variable from stackoverflow.com/questions/23063474/ but that does not seem to help, I get the same compile error.

EDIT2: Clarified the "intent" of the example code.

EDIT3: renamed `Map` to `MyMap`, apparently it is too confusing to define a custom `Map` type.

Comment: For me the error seems to be to **write** such code in the first place. When you read 5 lines of code 5 times, and you still have no clue what is going on ... that always gives me the creeps.

Comment: And just for the record: is "Map" your own class? Otherwise *new Map()* doesn't compile with *any* java compiler.

Comment: I am finding the intent of this code hard to understand. `Unification` doesn't have a generic type, but its inner classes have generic types? What's the idea behind this then?

Comment: That's a result of abstracting away every other detail. I'm merely showing the issue without any semantic meaning to the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inference variable has incompatible bounds. Java 8 Compiler Regression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30622759/inference-variable-has-incompatible-bounds-java-8-compiler-regression)

Comment: @Ramses Yeah, thats the trouble with "minimal viable" example. Maybe it is minimal, and viable, but when readers are just confused all over the place ... (not blaming, just pointing out).

Comment: What kind of JDK do you use? Is it Eclipse build-in compiler?

Comment: I am not getting any error in my intellij IDE. I also added main method to see run time error, but still no error.

Comment: @AniruddhaDas just add psvm method and try run it..

Comment: I compile it using an ant script with JDK 1.8.0_102.

Comment: @Andremoniy I have added that and still no error at run time. jdk 1.8.0_101

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23063474/why-does-this-java-8-program-not-compile

Comment: I'm happy that Java does not compile this. ``getMap`` could return something like ``new Map<Integer, String>`` which would be valid for ``getMap``, but would not be a valid argument for ``setMap``.

Comment: @cello: ``Map`` is the ``Map`` class defined in the same file which has the correct constraints on its types. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be circumvented by introducing an intermediate method and thereby forcing javac to do the type inference in two stages. The first method only takes one type parameter and leaves the second one as a wildcard. Javac is able to correctly infer the single type parameter to this method. The second, and original, method is then able to correctly infer the second type parameter from the supplied argument.

```
public class Unification {

    final class Box<A> {}

    final class MyMap<A, B extends Box<? extends A>> {}

    MyMap<?, ?> getMap() {
        return new MyMap<Object, Box<Object>>();
    }

    <A> void setMap(final MyMap<A, ?> m) {
        doSetMap(m);
    }

    <A, B extends Box<? extends A>> void doSetMap(final MyMap<A, B> m) {}

    void worksFineNow() {
        setMap(getMap());
    }

}
```